# Best Disk Partitioning Scheme for a Linux-based Developer Machine

Tags: partition, system-installation

Is there some kind of "best disk partitioning scheme" for a Linux-based web and application **developer machine**, in terms of performance, organization or others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partitioning doesn't affect performance so much, but yes, file systems and their configuration affect performance. Look at this [benchmark](http://deinoscloud.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/whats-best-ext3-or-ext4-for-my-nfs-datastores/). For a little information about mounting options, see [fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#atime_options) at the ArchWili; especially look at `atime` options.

Partitioning has nothing with organization files in Linux, because in Linux everything is mounted into one tree.

I recommend one partition for the root filesystem, `/`, and separate partitions for folders where you place your work and personal data: `/home` and `/var/www` if you put your websites here, because if you change distro you will no need to do backup.

You may make partitions/disks based on files organization and their importance.

For example, you have got projects and documents which are very precious, then you can have them on RAID-ed disks. Also you may have remote disk mounted with ssh/ftp.

Mounting scheme:

```
/                      -> SSD disk, partition 1
/home                  -> SSD disk, partition 2
/tmp                   -> tmpfs
/media/data            -> RAID-ed disk, partition 2 (ie. shared photos with family)

user mounts:
/home/miroslav/secure  -> RAID-ed disk, partition 1 (encrypted)
/home/miroslav/remote  -> sshfs/curlftpfs
```

To mount `remote` and `secure` directories you will probably need some script that asks you for password(s).

Directory sym-links `pwd=/home/miroslav`:

```
projects       ->  secure/projects
documents      ->  secure/documents
mails-dir      ->  secure/mails
```

Answer (score 3):

On our internal developement virtual machines we use three partitions:

1. `/root` partition - housing mostly static operating system stuff
2. `/var` partition - for all dynamic data
3. `/home` partition - this is where development takes place with the user accounts of the developers

The reason to separate the partitions is to avoid a system halt due to full filesystem. If `/home` is full - does not matter. No running processes are affected. Delete something, enlarge online and continue.

`/` should not change much (the only exception is `/tmp` - but files there are usually never big).

`/var` is the place where `/var/tmp` and all other "live" data resides (including `/var/log`). A full `/var/log` is still the number one reason for system/application failures, so `/var` has to be big enough and there has to be a warning in time when space is becoming sparse there...

On physical machines, where disk space does not matter that much, we divide up additional "partitions" (mostly LVs), including: `/var`, `/var/tmp`, `/var/log`, `/tmp`, `/boot`, ... but these are production machines, where uptime matters.

Answer (score 1):

At a minumum, I'd do:

- 1 partion for `/`
- 1 partition for `/home` (this would be most of the space)

Comment: is this the best approach? ;)

Comment: For a dev-machine it is the approach which is the simplest. It divides up into system-space and dev-space.

Answer (score 1):

I used to make separate partitions for `/`, `/home`, `/usr/local` and `/var`, but I always seemed to end up with some sort of interactions across partitions. If I did install a different distro, I would want to have the unused dotfiles removed for simplicity, so I still made a backup and wiped `/home`.

As for making a `/var` partition, I made so many sites at school (~100 or so), with such a large variance in sizes between media heavy sites and text only exercises, that it was impossible for me to accurately estimate the amount of space to allocate.

Now, I just have one partition for everything, and I don't come anywhere near filling it up. Personal media (movies, games, shows) go on an external HD, so that I can take it to a friend's house. For virtual machines, which have to be virtual appliances in virtualbox if you want to move them, I like to have a dedicated flash drive for each one.

I've never seen a HD crash, but if it did, I don't think it would matter how the physical drive was partitioned; it would just be dead. The riskiest thing I've ever done with my HD is resizing partitions, which is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From experience probably the most manageable best partition scheme looks like this:

- `/`  (`/Dev` `/etc` `/root` `/run` `/opt` `/mnt` `/media`) 40 GB (for mounting large files)
- `/usr` (`/bin` `/sbin` `/lib` `/lib64`) 10 GB
- `/tmp` 8 GB (download file size max 6 GB)
- `/var` 20 GB (don't want Linux jamming keep big)
- `/boot` 1280 MB
- `/home` (rest)
- `/home/bin`  512 MB

**Why like this?**

For `/`, it's practical to mount it read-only minus `/etc`, but once system is fully configured, you want your system to feel fresh after every boot and that is an important step.  Also you can safely mount these with `noexec` `nosuid` `nodev` without much in the way of consequence.

For `/usr` ideally you will mount as read only to stay fresh, but the odd time you update just remount as `rw`, no biggie; safely use `nodev`.

`/tmp` and `/var` because you can't make read only and want to use `nodev` `nosuid` `noexec`.

`/boot` for obvious reasons, read-only (`ro`) `nodev` `nosuid` `noexec`.

Why the separation between `/home` and `/home/bin`, so that I can `chown root /home/bin` and give it `exec` privileges, and deny those same privileges to `/home`.  So scripts must be run as sudo and from that directory.

BTW, `/proc` and `/sys` are virtual file systems created by the kernel. Therefore can be mounted as desired in `fstab`.